# How to get jth through kth line using regex?

Tags: regex

is there a regex to extract range of lines for example 4th to 6th lines only
for example (but regex should be generic, at some point i will be changing required lines to be parameterized ), below should return

```
<edgeData file="e1det_-143547931#1_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_-143547931#1_1"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_143547931#0_0-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_143547931#0_0"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_143547931#0_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_143547931#0_1"/>
```

full data

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<additional>
    <edgeData file="e1det_-143547931#1_0-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_-143547931#1_0"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_-143547931#1_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_-143547931#1_1"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_143547931#0_0-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_143547931#0_0"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_143547931#0_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_143547931#0_1"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_143551389#1_0-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_143551389#1_0"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_143551389#1_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_143551389#1_1"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_-143547931#2_0-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_-143547931#2_0"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_-143547931#2_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_-143547931#2_1"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_143547931#1_0-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_143547931#1_0"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_143547931#1_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_143547931#1_1"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_143553082#1_0-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_143553082#1_0"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_143553082#1_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_143553082#1_1"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_-143551389#1_0-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_-143551389#1_0"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_-143551389#1_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_-143551389#1_1"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_143551389#0_0-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_143551389#0_0"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_143551389#0_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_143551389#0_1"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_348320661#1_0-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_348320661#1_0"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_348320661#1_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_348320661#1_1"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_-143553082#1_0-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_-143553082#1_0"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_-143553082#1_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_-143553082#1_1"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_-348320661#1_0-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_-348320661#1_0"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_-348320661#1_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_-348320661#1_1"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_143553082#0_0-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_143553082#0_0"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_143553082#0_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_143553082#0_1"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_348320661#0_0-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_348320661#0_0"/>
    <edgeData file="e1det_348320661#0_1-results-aggregated.xml" id="e1det_348320661#0_1"/>
</additional>
```

Comment: Yes, there is a regex for this.  Can you add some sample data and expected output to make this a complete question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regex pattern which will arbitrarily match the 4th through 6th lines inclusive of some input:

```
(?:.*\n){3}(.*\n.*\n.*\n)
```

or, maybe in Notepad++

```
(?:.*\R){3}(.*\R.*\R.*\R)
```

This pattern consumes, without capturing, the first three lines, then captures the next 3 lines in a capture group.

### Demo

Note that you generally should *not* use regex to parse XML content.  But, in your case, since you just want to extract entire lines, without regard to nested tags, there should be no problem.

Comment: Try using `(?:.*\R){3}(.*\R.*\R.*\R)` instead, and make sure you turn _off_ DOT ALL mode in the regex options.

Comment: can this expression be parameterized ??

Comment: I can't say that I honestly know exactly what you are asking for.  What does "parameter" mean here?

Comment: got it, (?:.*\n){**x**}((.*\n){**y**})